# Refresh the app when came from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

in my app i have a mainViewController which take the info from a server.
i want to keep the mainViewController up to date so when the user came from background i need to update the data.

i tried this code

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [defaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"exitTime"];

    [defaults synchronize];

}




- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSDate *exitTime = [defaults objectForKey:@"exitTime"];

    NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];

    //This will return the number of seconds elapsed:

    NSTimeInterval diff = [currentTime timeIntervalSinceDate:exitTime];

    NSLog(@"time gap %f", diff);


    if (diff > 300.0f){

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"UpdateUINotification" object: nil];


    }
```

this is what i put in each of my ViewControllers:

```
//in viewDidLoad:
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(update:) name: @"UpdateUINotification" object: nil];
    Finally, declare the update: method that will be called when the notification is triggered.



-(void)update{
    mainViewController *main = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:main animated:YES];
}
```

that code is working pretty well, but i have 20+ ViewControllers in my app so my question is, there is any way to reload the app (because mainViewController is my initial view) or to do it local for all the viewControllers in the app?

Comment: you have have a ParentUIViewController and make all classes to inherit this, add your logic to host a notification center. Reloading the app ? may be you can switch off your app's functionality to work in background or reset your rootviewcontroller so that everything starts from the scratch

Comment: I don't want the app to work on background. I just to refresh it when the user came from background and more then 5min past. How can i reset the app?

Comment: do you have a login flow in your app ?

Comment: I think this is not the right way to `[self.navigationController pushViewController:main animated:YES];` every time when comes from background as mainViewController is the initial view so you can do `[self.navigationViewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO]` and then on `mainViewController`'s  method `ViewWillAppear` you can request to server and update your app.

Comment: @thndrkiss yes i have..

Comment: @whack where should i put it? In all of my viewControllers?

Comment: You can Create `RootUIViewController` with this function `[self.navigationViewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO]` and then inherit all others `ViewControllers` so you need to just write this notification observer in your parent call this will `popToRootView`.

Comment: @whack, viewWillAppear may not be the right place for service call, it could get called multiple times if user goes to detailed view and gets back to main view http://www.learnprogrammingios.com/2013/10/viewcontroller-lifecycle.html

Comment: Yeah, you are right but number of solution are there as what i know about your flow you can add and `BOOL` in parent class and if then set the value `true` if call comes from `notification` and then check this in your child like (`mainViewController`) if yes then request to server otherwise no need to request.

Comment: @whack can write an example code? I'm a little confused.

Comment: @OshriALM review this https://github.com/BuntyM/Oshri_Demo

Comment: @whack thank you for the code bro, but its now what i need. [self.navigationViewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO] do nothing.. i need something like the AppDelegate or to put the notif in evert class i have..